# CSS Blur Overlay

Tags: html, css, blur

Как создать такой эффект в `CSS`?

[image: blur эффект]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используется не самое сложное `CSS` свойство `filter`.

Пока НЕ рекомендую писать без префиксов, так что всегда добавляйте их.

```
filter: blur(ваше значение в пикселях)
```

```css
body {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.blur {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: blur(13px); /*тот самый эффект blur который нужен*/
  -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
}

.widget {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/*  не обязательно  */

.text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 340px;
}

.text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 57px;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.text p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget center">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="text center">
    <h1 class="">какой то текст</h1>
    <p>тут можно кликать :)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```